# Is there a way of ordering the applications alphabetically?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo

Can I order the apps alphabetically or group them into folders?

Or maybe there's a better way of managing with an ever increasing number of installed apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I order the apps alphabetically

The app drawer already does this for you.

> or group them into folders?

Long press on the home screen.  Click folders.  Click New folder.  Click on the folder to open it.  Click on the "Folder" at the top to rename it.  Drag and drop apps into the folder from the app drawer to place them into the folder.

> Or maybe there's a better way of managing with an ever increasing number of installed apps?

I can also recommend [Apps Organizer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apps-organizer/com.google.code.appsorganizer).

Comment: +1 for Apps Organizer (although my system appears to slow down with it installed - not sure if that's just my imagination, or what). Wish I could give another +1 because I'm a noob and didn't realize that Android had built in folders. You may want to update that it's a long click at the top of the folder to rename it.

Answer (score 2):

Install [AppZorter](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.demidoes.appzorter.lite) app.

This is for Froyo or newer devices with TouchWiz (Samsung devices only).